# UIViewRepresentable ignores constraints of wrapped UIView

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

I have subclass of `UIButton`, which defines it's height inside by using `NSLayoutConstraints`, which I need to reuse in `SwiftUI` view by wrapping it into `UIViewRepresentable`.

So here is the code:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestButtonWrapper()
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}

final class TestButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)
        // these are ignored:
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    }
}

struct TestButtonWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> TestButton {
        let view = TestButton()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: TestButton, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Result is:

[image: Screenshot]

**Important:**
I can't remove constraints from `TestButton` and set frame inside `TestView`. This `UIKit` button is being reused in regular `UIKit` screens

How it can be solved? Why `UIViewRepresentable` ignores constraints of it's children?

Answer (score 4):

SwiftUI and UIKit's layout constraints are not the same...

One approach is to override `intrinsicContentSize` in your `TestButton` instead of trying to set constraints.

Give this a try:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestButtonWrapper()
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}

final class TestButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    
    func setup() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)
        // these are ignored:
        //heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        //widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    }
    
    // add this override
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return .init(width: 300.0, height: 200.0)
        
    }
}

struct TestButtonWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> TestButton {
        let view = TestButton()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: TestButton, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

For clarification...

When using UIKit auto-layout:

- the **constraints** define the size
- `intrinsicContentSize` has no effect

When using SwiftUI:

- `intrinsicContentSize` defines the size
- the **constraints** have no effect

We can use the same `TestButton` class in both environments:

```
// if this class is used in a UIKit auto-layout environment
//  its width and height constraints will define the size of the button
//  intrinsicContentSize will have no effect

// if this class is used in a SwiftUI environment
//  its width and height constraints will have no effect
//  intrinsicContentSize will define the size of the button (absent any other sizing actions)

final class TestButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    
    func setup() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)

        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return .init(width: 300.0, height: 200.0)
        
    }
}
```

So, for a SwiftUI implementation:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20.0) {
            Text("SwiftUI")
            TestButtonWrapper()
                .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}

struct TestButtonWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> TestButton {
        let view = TestButton()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: TestButton, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

and here is a Storyboard / UIKit implementation:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Storyboard / UIKit"
        
        let btn1 = TestButton()
        btn1.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.spacing = 20.0

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(btn1)
    }
    
}
```

Both produce the same output:

[image] [image]

Comment: Hi DonMag, thanks for answer! I can't remove these constrains as this button is used in old screens with UIKit AutoLayout. Is there any way to make intrinsicContentSize respect constraints?

Comment: @TimurMustafaev - if you're also using `TestButton` in a UIKit environment, leave the width and height constraints in there (just un-comment them). `intrinsicContentSize` tells auto-layout: *"this is the size I want to be **if nothing else sets my size**"*

Comment: but that's the problem, it's not working :D It is uncommented in my example, but intrinsicContentSize ignores these constraints

Comment: @TimurMustafaev - see the **Edit** to my answer.